# Change keyboard layout permanently

Tags: keyboard

I want to permanently change my keyboard layout. Every time I restart my computer, I have to add Spanish ISO layout and delete the US one.

My Macbook has a spanish keyboard but I use OSx in english.

Answer (score 1):

You can rearrange the languages from System Preferences > Languages. Don't delete English but put Spanish ISO first. I've it like that and the config sticks through restarts and the like.

Comment: The OQ is about the keyboard layout, not the language used by the system.

Comment: If he puts Spanish first in the Language list, his OS will be in Spanish, but he wants it in English.

Comment: I will check tomorrow how exactly I have it setup, but I have the OS in English and the Keyboard in Spanish ISO with no problems. Sorry for the misguiding of my answer, I promise to share a better one tomorrow.

Comment: I can't rearrange the input source, english is always first

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue by deleting the `HIToolbox.plist` file after changing the keyboard layout under System Preferences.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist
```